# Ajax not posting Select Option

Tags: ajax, django

I'm trying to get the value of the option in my template below called exampleid.  I've followed several examples I found online, but nothing seems to work.  My template below has the ajax and jquery to get the value but when I try to print it returns None.  I've exhausted my resources and my professor doesn't seem to know, he's "looking into it".

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title ="accesslevelid" class="form-control" id="accesslevelid" onchange="accesslevelid" title="">
            <option value="7"> Option 1</option>
            <option value="5"> Option 2</option>
            <option value = "3"> Option 3</option>

</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#accesslevelid').on('change', function () {
        var accesslevelid = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({ url: "{% url 'submitted' %}",
                headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                data: {
                  accesslevelid: accesslevelid,
                },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                  alert(result);
                },
              });
      });
  });
</script>
```

my view attempting to retrieve the value of the post.

```
exampleidpost = request.POST.get('accesslevelid', False)
print (exampleidpost)
```

My desired result is for the POST to return a 7,5, or 3.

Comment: This seems like a server issue (Django side). You can also post Python codes here, if you want. You can display the 7, 5, and 3 by rendering it using Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **csrf token** to you ajax request,
Try this way.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title="accesslevelid" class="form-control" id="accesslevelid" >
    <option value="1"> Option1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option3</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#accesslevelid').on('change', function () {
        var accesslevelid= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({ 
             url: "{% url 'submitted' %}",
             headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
             data: {
                 accesslevelid: accesslevelid
             },
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (result) {
               alert(result);
             },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And you no longer need a form.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but now when I try to get the post it states: MultiValueDictKeyError at /account/example/
"('examplelid', False)"  Which, i believe it's because there isn't a value.  I also, updated my code and I still need the form because there is a lot more to post than just the select option.

Comment: @student101 request.POST.get('accesslevelid', False)

Comment: Ok the multivaluedict key error went away, but now it just writes False to the print instead of the select option value.

Comment: I seen the edit for adding 'POST' instead of POST and that returns a value now instead of None.  Thank you Davit!